# При сохранении scss файла выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Когда сохраняю `scss` файл выводится ошибка:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: node_modules\node-sass\test\fixtures\depth-first\_vars.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$import-counter".
        on line 1 of node_modules/node-sass/test/fixtures/depth-first/_vars.scss
>> $import_counter: $import_counter + 1;
   -----------------^

    at options.error (D:\useful\Nastya\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

Вот gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('./**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./')); 
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch('./**/*.jade', ['jade']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.scss', ['sass']);
})
```

Comment: Ну, во-первых, судя по инструкции в галп, вы все scss будете генерировать в отдельный css, во-вторых, тут больше важно понимать что находится в *.scss и где определена эта переменная которую вы пытаетесь переопределить строкой `$import_counter: $import_counter + 1;`, так как ошибка явно дает понять, что переменная не определена, что странно, ибо её переопределение находится на первой строке. Если она у вас определена в другом файле, то вам надо позаботиться о том, что бы этот файл импортировался перед переопределением.

Comment: Содержимое scss файла `body {
  margin: 0;
  background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
}`

Comment: Нет, тут скорее вопрос именно в том, что не понятно как вы пытаетесь использовать переменную которой нет ... то есть вы её пытаетесь переопределить используя её же саму, при этому так как это первая строка, то соответственно в этот момент её вообще не существует

Comment: Я вообще никаких переменных не объявлял и не использовал

Comment: Это как?) В ошибке же четко написано какой файл вызывает ошибку при попытке сгенерироваться - "node_modules/node-sass/test/fixtures/depth-first/_vars.scss"

Comment: Могу скрин прислать

Comment: `return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')` - вот эта строка означает, что галп будет брать каждый файл с расширением scss в любой дирректории начиная с корня (ну и в дальнейшим его преобразовывать в отдельный css), когда он находит _vars.scss, то на первой строке он находит запись `$import_counter: $import_counter + 1;` в которой `$import_counter` просто напросто не существует в данный момент, вы делаете что-то типа `undefined + 1`, соответственно он выплевывает ошибку

Comment: У меня сейчас та же проблема. С той же самой переменной, хотя в стилей то толком даже еще и нет. Так что могу лишь подтвердить, что человек вас не обманывал :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения можете положить свои стили не в корень, а например `./css` и уже следить за ней.

**Что могло пойти не так**

Судя по логу ошибка в `_vars.scss` самом модуле `node_modules/node-sass/...`, но так как в условиях у вас указаны `./**/*.scss` (все SCSS начиная с корня), то вы пытаетесь скомпилировать и этот файл тоже.